# Uploading unprojected shapefiles using GeoServer REST API

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, coordinate-system, rest

I have a number of shapefiles that lack the `.prj` file. I'm able to upload them to GeoServer using the REST API. However, I'm unable to serve them after upload. Which brings me to the question as to whether I need to reproject before uploading to GeoServer. If I need to reproject, then which options are available?

I'm using GeoServer 2.1.3.

UPDATE: Layers created from the shapefile lack projection information. When I update the `Declared SRS` field, the layers are served without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the projection of the shapefiles then you can just create (or download from http://spatialreference.org) the necessary projection string and save it as a .prj file before you upload. See http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/prj/ for example.

If you don't know the projection of the files then you aren't going to manage to display them properly anyway :-).

Comment: Thanks loads. What if the shapefile has no projection at all? (I'm assuming its possible to have a shapefile without projection.)

Comment: If you wan to display the data on a map you must have a projection of some sort, otherwise it's just numbers on a graph

Comment: Thanks Iant. It seems my shapefiles are using the `4326` projection. Incorporating that projection info works perfectly.